# how do I parse certain data points from a .txt file through python 3.0

Tags: python, parsing

I have a file called CrimeReport.txt and it has information in this format.

```
{"lang": "en", "favorited": false, "truncated": false, "text": "Active crime scene on I-59/20 near Jeff/Tusc Co line. One dead, one injured; shooting involved. Police search in the area; traffic stopped", "created_at": "Fri Jan 31 05:51:59 +0000 2014", "retweeted": false, "source": "<a href=\"http://tapbots.com/software/tweetbot/mac\" rel=\"nofollow\">Tweetbot for Mac</a>", "place": {"country_code": "US", "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/cf44347a08102884.json", "country": "United States", "place_type": "city", "bounding_box": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-86.926154, 33.267324], [-86.598948, 33.267324], [-86.598948, 33.471006], [-86.926154, 33.471006]]]}, "contained_within": [], "full_name": "Hoover, AL", "attributes": {}, "id": "cf44347a08102884", "name": "Hoover"}, "user": {"id": 15220806, "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", "profile_text_color": "333333", "followers_count": 118021, "location": "Alabama", "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", "listed_count": 1705, "utc_offset": -21600, "statuses_count": 76381, "description": "Media meteorologist. WeatherBrains host. Weather geek.", "friends_count": 52014, "profile_link_color": "0084B4", "profile_image_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1890149584/spannwantsyou_normal.jpg", "geo_enabled": true, "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/15220806/1381811159", "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "screen_name": "spann", "lang": "en", "profile_background_tile": false, "favourites_count": 27, "name": "James Spann", "url": "", "created_at": "Tue Jun 24 16:02:10 +0000 2008", "time_zone": "Central Time (US & Canada)", "protected": false}, "retweet_count": 66, "id": 429129916446031872, "favorite_count": 4}
```

This is just one line in CrimeReport. All other lines are the same format as this given line. My question is how to use Python 3.0 to go through each line and parse data from "text".

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried and what isn't working, asking for a complete solution to a general programming problem is too broad for SO.

Comment: Use a newer version than 3.0.  It has IO problems and was quickly replaced by 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like JSON data so just go through it line by line. This is similar to Joran's answer except I've kept a loop so that "text" from each record can be handled independently.

```
import json

with open("CrimeReport.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        text = json.loads(line)["text"]
        ... do your work ...
```

Comment: your nicer than me :P

Answer (score 1):

here is **one** way you could do it

```
import operator,json,functools
the_text = functools.reduce(operator.add,map(operator.itemgetter("text"),map(json.loads,open(fname,"rb"))))
```

Comment: In python 3 that would be `functools.reduce`